# Add views to UIStackView and have them shrink in width of the screen width runs out

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` in storyboard like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
```

I want to be able to add views to this `UIStackView` programmatically like this:

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = .gray        
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
```

Initially, the views added will be 50x50 in dimensions. When only a few are added, I want them to stay 50x50 and be centered in the screen.

But when you add more than there is width on the screen, I want them to shrink in size.

Here is what I want it to look like. The first row is with three 50x50 views added. The next row has more added and notice how they shrink in width to fit the width of the screen:

[image]

Is this possible with a `UIStackView` and adding views programmatically like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible.
You can set set the following thing:

**Constraints:**

1. Add some height constraint that you want.
2. Add minimum width to stack view.
3. Add X and Y position to stack view.

[image]

**StackView Properties:**

1. Set alignment to fill.
2. Set distribution to fill equally.
3. Add some spacing, I've added 5.
   [image]

**Code:**

1. Take IBOutlet of stack view width in UIViewController class.
2. Calculate width of stack view as:

```
width = ({number of subviews} * {width of one subview}) + ({number of subviews - 1} * {stack view spacing added in step 3 of properties})
```

3. Set this width to constraint of stack view when update or add remove on subviews.

Now, add subviews programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with auto layout constraints only... no need to "calculate" sizing.

Start with a stack view:

- `UIStackView`

  - horizontal axis
  - spacing as desired
  - `Distribution: Fill Equally`
- constrain the Height to `50`
- constrain centerX to view centerX
- constrain Leading `greaterThanOrEqualTo` view leading plus 8-points ("side padding")
- constrain Trailing `lessThanOrEqualTo` view trailing minus 8-points ("side padding")

Every time you add an arranged subview, give it a `Width` constraint of `50` -- but with a `Priority` of `.defaultHigh`.

That tells auto layout: *"TRY to make the view 50-points wide. If you *can't*, then use the next auto layout command for its width."* In this case, the "next" command will be the stack view's `Fill Equally` property.

Here's some quick example code. A stack view near the top, starting with one subview... along with "Add" and "Remove" buttons:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // stack view properties
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 6

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            
            // we want height always at 50-points
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            
            // keep left and right ends of stack view AT LEAST 8-points from the sides
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // centered horizontally
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // "Add" and "Remove" buttons
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        
        cfg.title = "Add"
        
        let addBtn = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction() { _ in
            self.addView()
        })
        
        cfg.title = "Remove"
        
        let remBtn = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction() { _ in
            self.removeView()
        })
        
        addBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        remBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addBtn)
        view.addSubview(remBtn)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            addBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            addBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            remBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addBtn.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            remBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            remBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            remBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addBtn.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // start with one arranged subview
        addView()
        
    }
    
    func addView() {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        // tell autolayout to TRY to make the arranged subview 50-points width
        //  but allow it to "break"
        let w: NSLayoutConstraint = v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
        w.priority = .defaultHigh
        w.isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
    }
    
    func removeView() {
        // keep at least one arranged subview
        if stackView.arrangedSubviews.count > 1 {
            stackView.arrangedSubviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]